# updating object inside BEFORE DELETE trigger has no effect

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I need to clean up a deleted object within another object which uses it as a foreign key, and I use a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger for that.  I have no idea why the code below does not work.

Even more strange is that if I perform sequentially the UPDATE query and then DELETE query, the row is deleted properly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cleanNoteEventConnections() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'update invoice set "noteEvent"=null where "noteEvent"=' || OLD.id;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER cleanNoteEventConnections BEFORE DELETE ON note_event
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cleanNoteEventConnections();
```

This is what I see in the pgAdmin console after the delete query:

```
delete from note_event where id=34
result: Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 11 msec execution time.
```

And the `note_event` with id 34 still exists.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need for dynamic SQL here. `update invoice set "noteEvent"=null where "noteEvent" = OLD.id;`  will work just fine.

Comment: what do You mean dynamic SQL? (I am not database expert but I am really curious) Without the word "EXECUTE 'query...'? Could You show example? Does "statitc" SQL performs faster?

Comment: Yes, `execute` uses dynamic SQL (it runs an arbitrary SQL statement in a string). Just replace the line starting with `execute` with the example from my first comment

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> Row-level triggers fired `BEFORE` can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` does not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the operation proceeds with that row value.

Use `RETURN OLD;` instead of `RETURN NULL;`.